# How to read Excel file in Perl by sheet name

Tags: excel, windows, perl, spreadsheet

I am looking for some examples/advice on how to write a Perl script
to read data from an Excel file by sheet name and not sheet number.
This is an example with `Spreadsheet`, but it doesn't work with sheet name:

```
#Code Perl :
use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);
{
    my $book  = ReadData ("test.xls");
    my $sheet = $book->sheet ("name_3");
    my @rows = rows ($sheet);
    ...
}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me when I use the [OO API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $book  = Spreadsheet::Read->new('test.xls');
my $sheet = $book->sheet('Sheet1');
my @rows  = $sheet->rows();
```